# Can I add a Color Picker to Django Forms

Tags: python, django, forms, color-picker

I tried using the django-colorfield module which works great for the admin page but I cannot get it to render the widget in the actual forms. Below is what I have tried so far and all I get on the form is a CharField with the default value as text. I am open to every and any suggestions but I do not want to use the RGB color picker that html5 has if possible.

## This is in my forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import Automation
from colorfield.fields import ColorWidget


def get_automation_form(content, data=None, files=None):
    songs = content[2].split(', ')
    music_choices = []
    for song in songs:
        song = song.replace(' ', '-')
        song_filename = f'Music/{song}.wav'
        music_choices.append((song_filename, song))

    class AutomationForm(forms.ModelForm):
        music_selection = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Select(choices=music_choices))
        class Meta:
            model = Automation
            fields = content[0]
            labels = content[1]
            widgets = {
                'color1': forms.CharField(widget=ColorWidget()),
                'color2': forms.CharField(widget=ColorWidget()),
                'color3': forms.CharField(widget=ColorWidget()),
                'color4': forms.CharField(widget=ColorWidget()),
                'color5': forms.CharField(widget=ColorWidget()),
            }

        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            super(AutomationForm, self).__init__(data=data, files=files,*args, **kwargs)

    return AutomationForm()
```

## This is in my models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from colorfield.fields import ColorField

class Automation(models.Model):
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default="", blank=True)

    text_field01 = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="")
    text_field02 = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="")
    text_field03 = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="")
    text_field04 = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="")
    text_field05 = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="")
    text_field06 = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="")
    text_field07 = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="")
    text_field08 = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="")
    text_field09 = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="")
    text_field10 = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="")

    image_field01 = models.ImageField(upload_to='client_image_inputs', default="")
    image_field02 = models.ImageField(upload_to='client_image_inputs', default="")
    image_field03 = models.ImageField(upload_to='client_image_inputs', default="")
    image_field04 = models.ImageField(upload_to='client_image_inputs', default="")
    image_field05 = models.ImageField(upload_to='client_image_inputs', default="")
    image_field06 = models.ImageField(upload_to='client_image_inputs', default="")
    image_field07 = models.ImageField(upload_to='client_image_inputs', default="")
    image_field08 = models.ImageField(upload_to='client_image_inputs', default="")
    image_field09 = models.ImageField(upload_to='client_image_inputs', default="")
    image_field10 = models.ImageField(upload_to='client_image_inputs', default="")
    image_field11 = models.ImageField(upload_to='client_image_inputs', default="")
    image_field12 = models.ImageField(upload_to='client_image_inputs', default="")
    image_field13 = models.ImageField(upload_to='client_image_inputs', default="")
    image_field14 = models.ImageField(upload_to='client_image_inputs', default="")
    image_field15 = models.ImageField(upload_to='client_image_inputs', default="")
    image_field16 = models.ImageField(upload_to='client_image_inputs', default="")
    image_field17 = models.ImageField(upload_to='client_image_inputs', default="")
    image_field18 = models.ImageField(upload_to='client_image_inputs', default="")
    image_field19 = models.ImageField(upload_to='client_image_inputs', default="")
    image_field20 = models.ImageField(upload_to='client_image_inputs', default="")

    video_field01 = models.FileField(upload_to='client_video_inputs', default="")
    video_field02 = models.FileField(upload_to='client_video_inputs', default="")
    video_field03 = models.FileField(upload_to='client_video_inputs', default="")
    video_field04 = models.FileField(upload_to='client_video_inputs', default="")
    video_field05 = models.FileField(upload_to='client_video_inputs', default="")
    video_field06 = models.FileField(upload_to='client_video_inputs', default="")
    video_field07 = models.FileField(upload_to='client_video_inputs', default="")
    video_field08 = models.FileField(upload_to='client_video_inputs', default="")
    video_field09 = models.FileField(upload_to='client_video_inputs', default="")
    video_field10 = models.FileField(upload_to='client_video_inputs', default="")
    video_field11 = models.FileField(upload_to='client_video_inputs', default="")
    video_field12 = models.FileField(upload_to='client_video_inputs', default="")
    video_field13 = models.FileField(upload_to='client_video_inputs', default="")
    video_field14 = models.FileField(upload_to='client_video_inputs', default="")
    video_field15 = models.FileField(upload_to='client_video_inputs', default="")
    video_field16 = models.FileField(upload_to='client_video_inputs', default="")
    video_field17 = models.FileField(upload_to='client_video_inputs', default="")
    video_field18 = models.FileField(upload_to='client_video_inputs', default="")
    video_field19 = models.FileField(upload_to='client_video_inputs', default="")
    video_field20 = models.FileField(upload_to='client_video_inputs', default="")

    color1 = ColorField(default="FFFFFF")
    color2 = ColorField(default="FFFFFF")
    color3 = ColorField(default="FFFFFF")
    color4 = ColorField(default="FFFFFF")
    color5 = ColorField(default="FFFFFF")

    music_selection = models.CharField(max_length=120, default="")
```

## This is my form.html

```
{% extends "main/base.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %}
{% a_form.media %}
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <input type="hidden" name="nickname" value="{{ builder.nickname }}" />
            <fieldset class="form-group">
                <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">{{ builder.title }}</legend>
                {{ a_form|crispy }}
            </fieldset>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The widget for a `ColorField` is the [**`ColorWidget`** [GitHub]](https://github.com/fabiocaccamo/django-colorfield/blob/master/colorfield/widgets.py). So in your form, you can use:

```
from colorfield.widgets import ColorWidget

class AutomationForm(forms.ModelForm):

    music_selection = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Select(choices=music_choices))
    class Meta:
        model = Automation
        fields = content[0]
        labels = content[1]
        widgets = {
            'color1': ColorWidget,
            'color2': ColorWidget,
            'color3': ColorWidget,
            'color4': ColorWidget,
            'color5': ColorWidget,
        }

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(AutomationForm, self).__init__(data=data, files=files,*args, **kwargs)
```

Note that in your template, you need to render the `media` of your form, so:

```
{{ form.media }}
<form …>
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% form.as_p %}
</form>
```

Comment: I am getting an import error when trying to import ColorPickerWidget.

ImportError: cannot import name 'ColorPickerWidget' from 'colorfield.widgets' (C:\Users\edwin.cruz\PycharmProjects\website\venv\lib\site-packages\colorfield\widgets.py)

Comment: @EdwinCruz: ah, apparently that was an old repository, the new one is `ColorWidget`.

Comment: Yes I tried that as well but it does not seem to render the actual widget in the html. I simply get what looks like a character field with the default hex I put in as text.

Comment: @EdwinCruz: did you add the `form.media` to the template?

Comment: @WillemVanOsem: I just added it but not I get an error TemplateSyntaxError. django.template.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: Invalid block tag on line 4: 'form.media', expected 'endblock'. Did you forget to register or load this tag? I added what I have in my html maybe that is where I am doing something wrong?

Comment: @EdwinCruz: sorry, made a typo. It is `{{ form.media }}` (so with double curly brackets)